# Cannot get Game Center to login to Sandbox mode (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, ios7.1

This is driving me nuts.

For the life of me I cannot get Game Center to login to Sandbox mode. I can see the sign on dialog when I open my app, and I can fill out all the information to make a new account, at which point I get "Internal server error"...but I never see the word "sandbox" displayed anywhere during the sign on.

I am logged out of Game Center in the Game Center app and have Game Center enabled in iTunes Connect. No matter what I do, Sandbox mode never seems to switch on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a sandbox account in the simulator and using the same credentials for the device.